# Android ProgressWheel for 10 seconds

Tags: android, android-progressbar

We are using `com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel` to show the recording is in progress. I am recording for 10 secs. I want to know how to show this `ProgressWheel` for 10 seconds and finish it at the end of 10 seconds. How to do that.

Comment: check https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress and find other options heading for more details

Comment: did you tried to use `setSpinSpeed()`??

Comment: you can use handler too

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CountDownTimer.

```
long total = 10000; // 10 seconds
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, updateTime) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // set the progress
        float progress = (float)((double)((total-millisUntilFinished)/total));
        progressWheel.setProgress(progress);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // do what you want to do, i.e. change an activity or something
    }
};
countDownTimer.start();
```